# SQL Server execution plan is suggesting to create an index containing all the columns in the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a key table with 2 columns: `Key`, `Id`.

In a stored procedure I've written, my code joins the `Employee` table to the `Key` column, then selects the `Id` - something like this:

```
SELECT 
    E.EmployeeName, K.Id 
FROM 
    Employee E
JOIN 
    KeyTable K ON E.Key = K.Key
```

The execution plan is suggesting to create the following index:

```
[schema].[Employee] ([Key]) INCLUDE ([Id])
```

My question is why? If all the information is in the table to begin with why create an index and duplicate that information?

Comment: Is it a heap table?, it doesn't have a primary key?

Comment: @Lamak Thats right, it doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: How large is that table? Is the query slow running?

Comment: @Mountaineer It isn't that large and the query isn't slow by any means. Just having a peak under the hood to see if there was anything I could proactively do to help performance. Damien (below) is right, at the moment every read is a scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because all of the information is "in the table", that doesn't mean that *searching the entire table* is going to be the most efficient way of obtaining the results for this query.

Here, the server is saying that, if it had a way to quickly locate rows in this table, given a `Key` value, that the query should be able to be processed more quickly (not that it's 100% reliable in its suggestions, so you should test before implementing).

This can be true if the table is a heap (no clustered index) or for a clustered table where the clustering key(s) don't match the desired access order for the query.

---

Also, if you think about it - *every* (non-clustered) index duplicates information. It's just that usually its a subset of the information rather than the whole set.

Comment: That is very true, I forgot about index vs scan and got a bit too focused on the fact that the plan was asking for all the columns. Thank you very much :)